# Optimization done by an EnumMap/EnumSet

Tags: java, collections, enums

I recently read an article about [`EnumMap`](http://javarevisited.blogspot.ch/2012/09/what-is-enummap-in-java-example-tutorial.html). It's written that *"using  EnumMap brings implementation specific benefits which is done for enum keys, In short `EnumMap` is optimized Map implementation exclusively for enum keys."*

It's also written that *"Enum is implemented using Arrays and common operations result **in constant time**. So if you are thinking of an high performance `Map`, `EnumMap` could be decent choice for enumeration data."*

---

Can someone point me out how this optimizations are done ? (*"operations result **in constant time**")*

Comment: The JDK is open source. And the sources come with the JDK. Why don't you read them?

Comment: Enums are internally int values so my guess is that this int values are simply used as index for an array of the map  values. But just as *JB Nizet* wrote, simply have a look at the source yourself.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation for EnumMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html):

> A specialized `Map` implementation for use with enum type keys. All of the keys in an enum map must come from a single enum type that is specified, explicitly or implicitly, when the map is created. Enum maps are represented internally as arrays. This representation is extremely compact and efficient.
>
> Enum maps are maintained in the natural order of their keys (the order in which the enum constants are declared). This is reflected in the iterators returned by the collections views (`keySet()`, `entrySet()`, and `values()`).

In short, an `EnumMap` is just an array, of the type of the values of the map. In other words, an `EnumMap<SomeEnum, SomeValue>`, would be just a `SomeValue[]`.

How are the indexes assigned, you might ask? They are assigned by the natural order of the enum. Example:

```
enum Day {
    MON, TUE, WED, THU, FRI, SAT, SUN
}
```

The above enum has the following natural order.

```
MON TUE WED THU FRI SAT SUN
 0   1   2   3   4   5   6
```

So, an operation like `map.put(Day.FRI, "Yay!")` can actually be viewed as:

```
array[4] = "Yay!";
```

Array access is a constant time operation, and that's why the `EnumMap` benefits of it as well. The look up (`get()`) works just the same way.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see from the [source](http://fuseyism.com/classpath/doc/java/util/EnumMap-source.html), an `EnumMap` contains an array of objects of length exactly the number of values in the `enum`. For (for instance) `put` and `get`, the ordinal value of the `enum` value is used as array index. This operation obviously takes constant time.

Answer (score 1):

An `EnumMap` is backed by an array of size the number of values in your `Enum`.

The array is then accessed thanks to the [`Enum.ordinal()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#ordinal%28%29) method when `getting` or `putting` data, which takes contant time.